# Ways to take advantage of high/low currency prices

Tags: foreign-exchange, currency

Currently 1 USD can buy around 0.88 EUR which is historically quite high (a few years ago it used to be 0.6-0.7). I live in The Netherlands and therefore use euros as a day-to-day currency. Now that the price is high, I guess it would be kind of smart to sell any dollars you have laying around and get euros for it.

When the price is low, it would maybe be smart to buy dollars or buy products priced in dollars (such as on ebay or amazon for example).

Are there any tips regarding what I could do when the dollar price is either high or low other than what I mentioned and given that I don't want to buy stocks but want to have something physical/tangible such as actual dollar bills, or products purchased online? For example currently I have about 150 dollars in cash and I will sell them soon (when the price is around 0.92) but after that I won't have any dollars. What could I do in such a situation?

Answer (score 2):

You could [buy a currency future](http://www.investopedia.com/articles/forex/10/introduction-currency-futures.asp). This is a contract to buy or sell a specified amount of a particular currency at some point in the future (as specified in the contract).

You'd likely need a margin account with a broker to do this. [This article](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/how-to-buy-currencies) mentions some possible brokers. It's possible to make large gains this way but equally its also possible to make major losses.

Comment: But I would like to have something tangible: for example buying something on ebay at a time where the euro price is very low. This means it will cost me less to purchase something online priced in dollars

Comment: You could buy something from another country but shipping costs will eat into any price differentials.

Comment: Though sometimes you'll buy something from another country without knowing it. I ordered a repair part thru Amazon and found that of the $20 I paid most was for pistage to mail a single unit from China. It was still a pretty reasonable price.